# Oracle database SQL developer - ERROR - DROP TABLE

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I create a table and wanted to drop the table, but i keep getting error
code ORA-00903 and i am using the admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop table "Engineers" - you've created a Case Sensitive object name, or someone has, and now you have to deal with it going forward anytime you want to work with it.

When creating things in Oracle, best not to quote the object names.

```
create table "Engineers" (a integer); -- not a good practice in Oracle...for reasons you have already seen

drop table engineers;
drop table Engineers;
drop table ENGINEERS;
drop table "Engineers"; -- this will work
```

Run that -

```
Table "Engineers" created.


Error starting at line : 3 in command -
drop table engineers
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 4 in command -
drop table Engineers
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 5 in command -
drop table ENGINEERS
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Table "Engineers" dropped.
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following key `drop` for deleting table

```
drop table tablename
```

Comment: i try using drop but i still get an error that the table or view does not exist error code 00942